# How to connect to wifi devices using Java?

Tags: java, wifi

How to establish connection in Java between devices within wifi range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To establish a connection between two devices over a network (WiFi, cable, etc...) you need to write 2 pieces of software:

1) A server: which waits for connections

2) A client: which initiates a connection to the server

Once the client initiates a TCP connection then the devices are connected and you can send data and messages between them.

Here: [Java Sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Here's a COMPLETE step by step tutorial on how to write a chat application: [Client/Server Pair](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)

Comment: @mani No problem buddy sorry if I sounded a little harsh. Hope this helps.

Comment: iam sorry,asking this question so many time. becuse  iam new to this j2me.. And i want to develop an application which can detect wifi or bluetooth devices with in the wifi or bluetooth range automatically and send a request to the device and establish a connection between to devices....

Comment: @mani Here's the thing, if the devices in range don't have your server installed then you won't be able to connect and do anything meaningful. What will the application do once you are connected?

Comment: location aware calculation using either bluetooth connection or wifi connection..... is it possible..??  and i thinking for that iam using java packages bluetooth (jsr 82) and location api(JSR 179)....

Comment: @mani It probably can but I'm not sure how. I suggest that you get a firm understanding on how TCP connections work first and then move into the more interesting stuff. Good luck!

Comment: yes I also understand the client & Server concept. But 
how about the wifi? how java deal with that? I mean the code @Pepe